# Excel autonumber range

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

Most of you know about this little feature of Excel, as well as almost any other spreadsheet software like Google Spreadsheets called [Autonumbers](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Automatically-number-rows-76ce49e3-d8d2-459b-bd85-ee1d3973e6e6). [Example](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Autonumber-in-Excel).

What I'd like to know if it's possible to do this drag trick when you have a `min` and `max` of the range. I'll show it as an example, note that `.` is the empty cell:

```
35
.
.
.
.
50
```

Here you may calculate this step `3` easily in this case and perform the trick on `35`, `38`. So the question is: is it possible to do without knowing the step, if the values are complex decimals like range `379.124 . . . 58.123`?

P.S. I tried selecting `min` and `max` using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and draggin the corner to the cells between with no success. Maybe there is a formula for that?

I ask this question because I thinks it's a pretty common problem and that developers of spreadsheet applications may have already implemented a solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that Excel handles this. Select your range with start/end values and then on the Home ribbon, select Fill -> Series.

Yes, it will also handle more complex ranges, such as your second example.

[image]

Comment: Am I right this is not available in google spreadsheet? Can't seem to find it anywhere as well as googling din't return anything on `Fill series`.

Comment: As well as `Libre Office` does not support at least guessing this. Maybe someone will have a solution to use with them. As for this thank you for this fast answer.